# while loop and input (<>) Perl

Tags: perl

How could make while loop w8 till user put somting in input?

```
$var = <>;
while(1){
somting $var;
}
```

Comment: `<>` allwayz w8s. Ur qeschun dont mak sens.

Comment: Maybe Hellena is a (lol) cat ?! =)

Comment: Not work... While loop make some other things before I put input :(

Comment: The string "w8" is not a word in the English language. Write English, not bingo.

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this :

```
use strict; use warnings;

print "type something >>> ";
chomp(my $var = <STDIN>);

while(1){
    print "type something from within the LoOp >>> ";
    chomp($var = <STDIN>);
    print "$var\n";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not work... While loop make some other things before I put input :(

Comment: Maybe the first read on STDIN ? -_-

Comment: +1 for your response, and I wish I could add another for the neko image!

Comment: Don't forget to "accept" the answers if it was well answered

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking so here's my two attempts..

If you mean keep waiting until a user inputs an initial value then:

```
my $var = <>;
```

should work fine.

If you want to continuously receive input in a loop, I would do:

```
while(my $var = <>){
    something($var);
}
```

For a more in depth look at this I recommend [this link.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators)

Comment: I need to user can input patch to some file home/hellena/Desktop/some.txt

Comment: Going on the assumption you want the user to enter a file path, that's perfectly okay if they enter it as a string :) 
Is there something not working? Try explain the errors that are occurring